# Python socket recv in thread

Tags: python

Here is my problem. I have a server on lua which sends data via socket. Data go constantly - it is a stream of exchange transactions. My python script as client should receive data.

```
def listen():

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    sock.connect(("localhost", 1111))

    with BytesIO() as response_bytes:
            while True:    
                try:
                    fragment = sock.recv(8196)    
                    print("Фрагмент: {}".format(fragment))
                except Exception:
                    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t2 = threading.Thread(listen())
    t2.start()

    while True:

        print ("test")
```

Main thread wait sock.recv(8196) line. I want that data from a socket were accepted in parallel, and the main stream continued to work. The current code blocks performance of main until listen is executed. I am not familiar with multiple tasks in Python. What decisions can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `listen` function to `threading.Thread()`. You're calling the function in the main thread, waiting for it to finish, and then passing its return value (which is just `None`, since the function never returns anything).

```
t2 = threading.Thread(target = listen)
```